# Change of basis - is the dot product method correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

The traditional way of expressing a vector in a differnet basis relies on change of basis matrix (see [here](https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/changebasis/))

I'm not sure why almost no book or online texts mention this, but there's another method. Is it correct? Suppose I have a vector expressed in standard basis $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n)$ and a set of basis vectors $B'=\lbrace b'_1, b'_2,..., b'_n\rbrace$. Then the new coordinates are:

$(x'_1, x'_2,...,x'_n)=(b'_1\cdot x,  b'_2\cdot x,...,b'_n\cdot x)$.

So every new coordinate is a dot product of the original vector and the respective basis vectors of the new basis. This is used for example in this [paper, see page 3, upper right part](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.1100v1.pdf)

How can we derive this method from the traditional one (change of matrix-based)? Intuitively, the method makes sense - we have a bunch of vectors forming a basis in our space. We take vectors in the old basis and project them onto the new basis vectors (that's the dot product). The respective results are the coordinates in the new basis.

**However, I'm not that sure if this is correct.** Let 
$B=\lbrace b_1, b_2,..., b_n\rbrace$ be the old basis,
$B'=\lbrace b'_1, b'_2,..., b'_n\rbrace$ be the new basis. We have a vector $x$ whose coordinates in basis $B$ are $[x]_B=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n)$.

It means that $x=x_1 b_1 + x_2 b_2 + ...+x_n b_n$.

To simplify, consider the $\mathbb{R^3}$ example.

$[x]_B=(x_1,x_2,x_3), B=\lbrace b_1, b_2, b_3\rbrace, B'=\lbrace b'_1, b'_2, b'_3 \rbrace$.

$x=a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + a_3 b_3$

$b_1=\alpha_1 b'_1 + \alpha_2 b'_2 + \alpha_3 b'_3$

$b_2=\alpha_4 b'_1 + \alpha_5 b'_2 + \alpha_6 b'_3$

$b_3=\alpha_7 b'_1 + \alpha_8 b'_2 + \alpha_9 b'_3$

Substituting, we get that $x=(a_1 \alpha_1 + a_2 \alpha_4 + a_3 \alpha_7)b'_1 + (a_1\alpha_2 + a_2 \alpha_5 + a_3 \alpha_8)b'_2 + (a_1\alpha_3 + a_2 \alpha_6 + a_3 \alpha_9)b'_3$.

So the coords of $x$ in the new basis $B'$ are:

$[x]_{B'}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}\alpha_1&\alpha_4&\alpha_7\\\alpha_2&\alpha_5&\alpha_8\\\alpha_3&\alpha_6&\alpha_9\end{array}\right]$$\left[\begin{array}{c}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{array}\right]$

**Notice above that the vectors in basis $B$ were put in COLUMNS, not ROWS!** Then it has nothing to do with dot product of the original vector $x$ with the vectors of the new basis. So how to get this dot product method from change of basis matrix?

I've tested a few examples and they worked (only if the basis vectors were normalized, of course)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** In the following, I assumed the new basis was an orthogonal
transformation of the old. This is evidently *not* the case in the
document cited in the question, which describes its transformation as
a "rotation and stretch." Various nice properties of the orthogonal
transformation (such as "the columns of the matrix are the rows of its
inverse") are not preserved then, so the discussion after the
dividing line (below) only partly applies.

In [the linked reference](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.1100v1.pdf),
in part B ("Change of Basis", on page 3)
there is a statement that the matrix $P$ represents a "rotation and stretch",
which seems to me to imply that the *columns* of $P$ are
pairwise orthogonal but not necessarily orthonormal.
At the end of that section it says the dot products of the rows of $P$ and
columns of $X$ (in the matrix product $PX$)
represent the projection of each column of $X$ onto rows of $P$.
If there is any "stretch" then this is not the usual kind of projection,
and the resulting column of $Y$ does not represent the coefficients of a
linear combination of rows of $P$ that would 
equal the original column of $X$, and I question the statement that the
rows of $P$ are a new set of basis vectors for expressing the columns of $X$.
They do not seem to be so in the usual sense.

---

The dot product method is valid.

There are two obvious ways to convert coordinates under
an orthogonal change of basis.
One looks like a rotation of all vectors around the origin to arrive at
new coordinates.
The other looks like the system of coordinates itself rotated while
all the vectors stayed in place.

An important property of these two rotations is that each is exactly
opposite the other, that is, they are inverse transformations of each other.
A simple example is if you have a piece of paper in front of you
with writing on it, but the lines of writing are all tilted so they go
from the upper left to lower right along a $45$-degree slope
instead of just left to right. To make it so that
you can see the text right-side up, you can either rotate the 
paper $45$ degrees counterclockwise, or you can tilt your head
$45$ degrees clockwise--same amount of rotation around the same axis,
but in opposite directions.

So if matrix $M$ would accomplish one of the methods of change of basis,
you need matrix $M^{-1}$ to do the other.

Another interesting fact about rotations is that the the matrix
$M$ that performs the rotation is orthogonal, and it has
the property that $M^{-1} = M^T$.
That is, the inverse of $M$ is just its transpose.

So that's how one matrix can put the basis vectors in columns and the
other can put them in rows.
One matrix corresponds to turning the paper, the other corresponds
to tilting your head.
They are inverses of each other, so the columns of one are the rows
of the other.

Comment: Matrix $M$ has to be orthogonal meaning its columns (which are coordinates of basis vectors in the other basis) should be unit vectors and be orthogonal? We're just forgetting they are coordinates and treat them as vectors, right? No matter in what basis they were expressed.

Comment: Am I right? Let me know, please...

Comment: It only works as neatly as I said if the rows are orthonormal. Unfortunately I did not follow the link or I would have recognized the tutorial and might have recalled it did not use an orthogonal transformation matrix. I'm editing in some words about that.

Comment: Sorry, it's on [page 3](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.1100v1.pdf), my mistake. (upper right part of the page), it says - 'the rows of P are a
new set of basis vectors for representing of columns of X'. It's true if the basis is a set of orthonormal vectors, which isn't mentioned.

Comment: Yes, that's what I found too. It does not seem to agree with earlier statements about $P$.

Answer (score 2):

**The "dot product method" is correct only when the corresponding basis is orthonormal.**

One has the following general fact: If $(f_k)_{1\leq k\leq n}$ is an orthonormal basis in a euclidean vector space $V$ then the coordinates $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ of a vector $x\in V$ with respect to this basis are given by
$$x_k=\langle f_k,x\rangle\qquad(1\leq k\leq n)\ .$$
*Proof.* $\qquad\langle f_k,x\rangle=\left\langle f_k,\sum_{j=1}^n x_j\>f_j\right\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^nx_j\langle f_k,f_j\rangle =x_k$.

When the "new" basis $(b_i')_{1\leq i\leq n}$ is not orthonormal, in particular: when  a scalar product is not even defined, then we need the exact coordinates of the $b_i'$ in terms of the old basis $(b_k)_{1\leq k\leq n}$ in order to build the so-called *transition matrix*.

Answer (score 1):

You might recognize this as the definition of matrix multiplication. Less succinctly, you might recognize that
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a&b&c \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} d \\e \\f \end{pmatrix} = ad + be + cf,
$$
and so on.

Comment: user2566092 said 'Just write the change of basis matrix when you assume you are going from standard basis to a new basis B. You should get that the change of basis matrix is simply the vectors in B written as rows of a matrix.'  Isn't it false? No matter how I try, all I get it is something different, that the vectors of new basis are written as COLUMNS, not rows. Then it's false that we can use dot product between vectors of new basis and our original vector to get the new coordinates... (check the edited question)

Comment: Please, help... It's a matter of one or two sentences for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the change of basis matrix when you assume you are going from standard basis to a new basis $B$. You should get that the change of basis matrix is simply the vectors in $B$ written as rows of a matrix. Then your formula follows immediately.